# Hide GET parameters with url rewriting in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this type of questions was already asked and answered, I've tried several ways to do it, but I can't make it work.
So I access to a page where I've a list of products and a pagination, for the moment to change the page the url is like that :

```
domain.com/brands?p=2
```

and I would like access it like that :

```
domain.com/brands/2
```

The last way i tried was this one :

```
RewriteRule ^brands/([0-9]*)$ brands?p=$1 [L]
```

but when I try to access to the page I get a 404 error.

So is there a mistake ? Or the problem is located somewhere else ? Like another url rewriting which interferes with this one ..

Comment: Doesn't you file have any extension? like .php or something?

Comment: There might already be a rewrite in place (which would be one explanation for the lack of file extension) which is interfering with this new rewrite - it might be that *brands* is a directory and the URL is really */brands/index.php*

Comment: Yes it has an extension, but as CD001 said, I guess there is already a rewriting on it. Actually i'm using a CMS (prestashop) and for the moment I don't really know what's the original file used.
At least I know the problem doesn't come from the Rules I tried.

Comment: Thanks you for your comments, actually I found that what was called was : index.php?controller=brands&p=2.
So I just put that in the RewriteRules and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that you can apply:

```
Rewriterule ^post/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?id_blogs=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /brands\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ brands/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^brands/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

make sure to ON the RewriteEngine using

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use following code to hide get parameters**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ /blog.php?slug=$1 [L]
```